# Quickest way to remove all references to a SQL field?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I've got a table called `Orders` which contains about 20 fields.

1 of these fields is called `Type`

I have a stored procedure in place called `sp_Orders`

This stored procedure is executed to a `SqlDataReader` on about 50 different ASP.NET pages for a variety of things.

I'm removing the `Type` field from the database, and therefore from `sp_Orders`

Using Visual Studio 2010, I've ran a 'Find in Files' for `sp_Orders` so I can find all occurances of `Type` and remove them.

However, not all executions of `sp_Orders` make use of `Type` so I'm now manually going through every occurance to see if it exists, and remove it.

Is there a quick way of finding all occurances of `sp_Orders` where the field `Type` is used?

Comment: not to mock you or anything, but this is why people use Data Access Layered n-tier architectures. The only way, that I see, to do this is manually check everywhere.. Tests would have helped too.

Comment: No thats fine, I take constructive critism. I've just never learnt about this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's a quick way to do this.  The quickest way would have been to centralise these calls when first written, but there you go...

Comment: Cheers for your reply Paddy. For future proof, what is the best way of centralising these calls?

Comment: By that I mean some kind of n-tier architecture, probably some kind of repository object that returns a list of orders - this is the only place that access the SP directly and many pages will call it.  If you google for n-tier or separation of concerns you should find a few articles... (kind of a broad question to really answer here).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll look into this later so I don't have to go through all these files again!